# Convert XML with binary content into readable text and back

Tags: python, web-development, xml

I am looking for software (or a Python library if such software is not available) that can convert the following type of .xml files into readable text. The library should be able to convert the readable text back to the original format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xmlarchive generator="IPS_KERNEL" created="1404545473" ipbLongVersion="34012" ipbHumanVersion="3.4.6">
  <fileset>
    <file>
      <filename>core.xml</filename>
      <content>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHRlbXBsYXRlcyBhcHBsaWNh&#13;
dGlvbj0iY29yZSIgdGVtcGxhdGVncm91cHM9ImE6MTI6e3M6MTI6JnF1b3Q7c2tpbl9lZGl0b3Jz&#13;
JnF1b3Q7O3M6NTomcXVvdDtleGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjExOiZxdW90O3NraW5fZW1haWxzJnF1b3Q7&#13;
O3M6NTomcXVvdDtleGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjExOiZxdW90O3NraW5fZ2xvYmFsJnF1b3Q7O3M6NTom&#13;
cXVvdDtleGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjE3OiZxdW90O3NraW5fZ2xvYmFsX290aGVyJnF1b3Q7O3M6NTom&#13;
cXVvdDtleGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjIwOiZxdW90O3NraW5fZ2xvYmFsX2NvbW1lbnRzJnF1b3Q7O3M6&#13;
NTomcXVvdDtleGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjk6JnF1b3Q7c2tpbl9oZWxwJnF1b3Q7O3M6NTomcXVvdDtl&#13;
eGFjdCZxdW90OztzOjEwOiZxdW90O3NraW5fbG9naW4mcXVvdDs7czo1OiZxdW90O2V4YWN0JnF1&#13;
b3Q7O3M6MTM6JnF1b3Q7c2tpbl9yZWdpc3RlciZxdW90OztzOjU6JnF1b3Q7ZXhhY3QmcXVvdDs7&#13;
```

The reason behind this question is that I'm installing some plugin for my forum (IPB), the plugin is provided as XML files, but I would like to make some modifications to it as I'm not happy with the default settings.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you know what the encoding of this content is? It doesn't look like Base64 which is what I would normally expect to see.

Comment: As stated above, you need to know the encoding method. Otherwise how is the software supposed to know what it should do? The only other possibilit is brute forcing most common methods or combinations of them, but it could as well be a very unique implementation.

Comment: But it does look to be just `base64` if you remove the repeating trailing `&#13;` So you can just use pure Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script with pure Python 3. These modules can help you:

- [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)
- [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)

As mentioned in the comment, to decode the value of `content`, you need to remove all the `&#13;` first, which seem to be carriage returns as HTML entities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!